# Where To Get A Route's Second Parameter From In A View?

Tags: php, laravel

My App evolves around a few models, including `User` and `Collection`. Between those there is a one (user) to many (collections) relationship.

In my `collections.create` view I want to set the action attribute to a route like this:

```
<form action="{{ route('users.collections.store') }}" method="POST">
```

I know there should be a second parameter in the route-function, but I don't know where to get it from.

My routes are:

```
Route::resource('users.collections', 'UserCollectionController');
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

Comment: Any `post` request will use the `store` method from a Resource Controller, there is no need to use `.store` at the end: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: ok, but if I omit the `.store` I get an error: `Route [users.collections] not defined`.

Comment: If you don't know the identifier then chances are you want to use `user.collections.create` and not `user.collections.store` because store is for editing an existing resource and not creating one

Comment: that's not true. `store` stores the data from a form displayed by `create`.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the parameter like following:

```
Route::get('user/{id}', function ($id) { // $id would be the parameter in this case
    return 'User '.$id;
});
```

There are optional parameters aswell, which you do not need to "fill" but can if you need to:

```
Route::get('user/{name?}', function ($name = null) {
    return $name;
});
```

Basically one is just adding a `?` wildcard.

And in your blade you can add the parameter like following:

```
<form action="{{ route('users.collections.store', [('user' => $var->user)] }}" method="POST">
```

To learn more there is a section regarding route parameter in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to hit a store method on your `UserCollectionController` you can do something like this:

**First** in your blade view you can pass a number of parameters to your rout like this:

```
<form action="{{ route('users.collections.store', ['someVariable' => $collection->someProperty, 'anotherVariable' => $user->anotherProperty])) }}" method="POST">
```

So now you can just edit the routes file to apply these changes, but you'll override the resource controller method you've created, so something like this (Btw the route in your code is not named):

```
Route::post('someWebPage/{someProperty}/{anotherProperty}', 'UserCollectionController@store')->name('users.collections.store');
```

And in your `UserCollectionController.php` of course you can accept them like this:

```
public function store(Request $request, $someProperty, $anotherProperty) { //Of course here you don't have to stick to the naming i'm just trying to make it clear
    // $collection = App\Collection::where('aProperty', $someProperty)-get();
}
```

I hope this is kind of what you wanted, hopefully it helps.

Comment: do I have to modify the default resource routes? Isn't there another (simpler) way?

Comment: You're not modifying anything, you're just overwriting the store route for the store method, all you need to do is as written in the answer I provided.